# Why does my program just hang?

Tags: java

I am trying to reverse an integer inputed by calling on a different method. I have this

```
import java.util.*;

public class reverseDigit
{

  public static int reverseDigit(int number) //digit reversing method
  {  
    int reverse= 0;

    while(number >= 0)
     {
      reverse = reverse*10 + number%10;
      number = number/10;
     }
   return reverse;
  }
 static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

 public static void main (String[]args) //main method
 {
  int number;

  System.out.println("Enter an interger to be reversed");

  number = console.nextInt();

  System.out.println(number+"reversed is:"+ reverseDigit(number));

 }
}
```

I've hit a wall so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Compiles without hanging for me

Comment: Your compiler isn't hanging, your program is. Its an infinite loop, see the answer.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your compiler is hanging.  I suspect that when you run your program it goes into an "infinite loop", but don't blame that on the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
while(number > 0)
```

When number gets zero then it stays zero and so you are in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your program is in an infinite loop caused by the line `while(number >= 0)`. Use of the debugger in your IDE would have helped you find this issue quickly. Replace that line with `while(number > 0)` to correct the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with Strings?

```
static int reverse(int number){
    String temp = String.valueOf(number);
    StringBuilder reversedTemp = new StringBuilder(temp);
    reversedTemp.reverse();
    return Integer.parseInt(reversedTemp.toString());
}
```

Or spice it up with a one-liner!

```
static int reverse(int number){
        return Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(number)).reverse().toString());
}
```